# How to pass extra parameters with laravel with function

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

How can we pass extra parameters with Laravel with function. I tried the following code but no luck.

```
$endpoints = MyModel::with(['myrelation' => function($q) use ($extraParams) {
    foreach ($extraParams as $param)
    {
        $q->orWhere('ia.paramCode','like',$param.'%');
    }
}])->get();
```

When I use this code it shows the following error

```
Cannot use lexical variable $extraParams as a parameter name
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which PHP version you are using?

Comment: sorry It was a typo

Comment: PHP 7.1.7 @AdnanMumtaz

Comment: remove  `$extraParams` from here `function($q,$extraParams)`

Comment: It should be `function($q) use ($extraParams, $otherParam)`

Comment: function($q) use (&$extraParams) {

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Thank you for your help. I'll try this method too.

Answer (score 3):

This happens in PHP 7 when you pass the same variable twice `(use ($extraParams)`. Simple fix is to rename `(use ($extraParams)` to `(use ($someThingElse)`

```
$endpoints = MyModel::with([
    'myrelation' => function($q) use ($extraParams){
        foreach ($extraParams as $param) {
            $q->orWhere('ia.paramCode','like',$param.'%');
        }
    }
])->get();
```

This is a Bug in PHP 7 apply quick fix.

Comment: Undefined variable: allOtherParams

Comment: @aishazafar this error generates when you pass the same variable name twice in the params to a function. so you have to change your  extra params to something else

Comment: Same issue undefined variable $allOtherParams

Comment: @aishazafar ```$endpoints = MyModel::with(['myrelation'=>function($q)
use ($extraParams){
                foreach ($extraParams as $param)
                {
                    $q->orWhere('ia.paramCode','like',$param.'%');
                }
            }])->get();``` use this code